# Unsupported type:TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE NOT NULL

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-flink

I am reading data from a PostgreSQL database into Flink, and using Table API and SQL. Apparently my timestamp column (called inserttime) is of type `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE NOT NULL`. But when I do an SQL query like `SELECT inserttime FROM books`, Flink is complaining that it is an unsupported type, with the error `Unsupported type:TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE NOT NULL`.

- Is this because of the `NOT NULL` at the end? If so, how should I cast it such that it can be read by Flink?
- I've tried to use a UDF to convert it to something readable by Flink, like below:

```
public static class TimestampFunction extends ScalarFunction {
    public java.sql.Timestamp eval (java.sql.Timestamp t) {
        // do some conversion
    }
}
```

Obviously, the eval function signature is wrong, but I'm wondering if this could be a method to get Flink to read my timestamp type? If so, what should the eval function signature be?

- I've also tried doing `CAST(inserttime as TIMESTAMP)` but the same Unsupported type error occurs.

Any ideas?

Comment: A database view casting the data type will most probably help...

Comment: What version of Postgres and where did you get it from? AFAIK there is no `TIMESTAMP() WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`.  Using client `psql` what does `\d books` show for a datatype for `inserttime`? Also JDBC driver version and source?

Comment: I'm using postgresql-42.2.10.jar. `inserttime` has JDBCType of `TIMESTAMP`.